# Tensorflow support for python 3.7.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.7

I'm trying to pip install tensor flow on python 3.7.4 and I get the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   tensorflow (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found
>   for tensorflow

From tensorflow installation site:

> Windows Python 3.5
>   CPU-only  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
>
> Python 3.5 GPU
>   support   https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.14.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
>
> Python 3.6
>   CPU-only  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
>
> Python 3.6 GPU
>   support   https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

It seems that there is not version for Python 3.7 in Windows. Is there any info about the release date of the new version?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip clearly mentions 3.7 support for Linux but doesn't seem to for Windows. Don't know anything about release dates, but a Linux (or possibly MacOS) machine might give you a workaround if you need to work with 3.7

Comment: @DavidBuck I'm on an important project and I need to check the compatibility of numerous packages. At the moment I could change to Python 3.6, but its good to know a workaround. Thanks David.